# Screen and application management software for Mac

Tags: mac, display

I open certain applications and place them in certain positions / screens depending on two factors: - working off the mains or battery AND working dual screen or on my Mac's laptop screen only.

At home I like to keep a lot of applications open for web development, etc.  A lot of these certainly consume battery so when out I like to keep only a subset open. It gets boring fast having to close, reopen each one individually.

Another problem I face is when I leave the house and its nice dual monitor setup, when I open up in a cafe all my screens are a mess because the apps all have to be placed onto one screen. Again, constantly pressing f8 to drag things around is a pain.

Are there any apps or even one wonder app that can solve this for me? Maybe select a work mode and it opens the apps automatically etc and positions them in my preselected spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Divvy](http://www.mizage.com/divvy/). It lets you specify shortcuts for window layout presets and it also works with multiple screens (it will load your preset onto the screen where the mouse cursor currently resides). I am not sure if it intelligently interacts with Apple's *Spaces* or simply works on the active space.

Note this app does not actually remember where specific windows go but rather lets you quickly resize and distribute open windows across your screen(s) according to user definable templates.

Comment: yes it doesnt remember where id like my apps to be but does make positiong them manually much faster. Looks like a great option if i cant find exactly what im looking for.